# composer install --prefer-source does not work

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a problem.I want to tell you with code.
Problem : composer install --prefer-source

Official Definition :will install the packages from their source which is usually a GitHub or a Subversion repository. In other words, it clones the package's source. In the case where the repository is not found on the vcs, it falls back to the installation from dist.

it is okey.no problem.

my composer.json is

```
    {
    "name": "root/composer",
    "require": {
        "blabla/url": "dev-master",
        "monolog/monolog": "^1.23"
    },
    "repositories" : [
        {
            "type" : "vcs",
            "url"  : "blabla/url"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is my composer.json file.The following code is run on terminal

```
composer install
```

**Cloning repository blabla/url on git is SUCCESSFULL!!!**

Packagist for 'blabla/url' is available.
***but is not same with git repository***

the above code worked for git repository.

Now..I change my composer.json file.

```
{
    "name": "root/composer",
    "require": {
        "blabla/url": "dev-master",
        "monolog/monolog": "^1.23"
    }
}
```

this is my composer.json file.The following code is run on terminal.

```
composer install --prefer-source
```

***this code worked for packagist,does not work for git repository***

**but Do not you need to upload it via git repository?**

What is problem?

Comment: What error messages are you getting exactly? And why did you remove the repositories section from the 2nd example?

Comment: hi.no error.updating ok!!! but if there is no 'repositories' in composer.json -- composer install --prefer-source it makes uploading from packagist.. if there is 'repositories' in my composer.json .. --prefer-source is unneeded..because it makes uploading from git repository with composer install